# Beer Clubs Online

Tags: buying

What is the best beer subscription service that people have found? I have wanted to get beers delivered to my doorstep that I have never tried before.

Comment: What country do you stay in?

Comment: We'd need to know some specifics about what qualities you think make the best service before we could give objective answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some US options.

The Bruery has a few different levels but their starter [Preservation Society](http://www.thebruery.com/societies/preservation-society/) gets you 3 bottles of different styles each quarter without any commitment (you can join for one quarter and quit any time). This is also the easiest way to get some of their big beers like Black Tuesday, White Chocolate, and Chocolate Rain. The contents of the 2015 4th quarter Preservation Society package includes:

- [Black Tuesday](http://www.thebruery.com/beer/black-tuesday/) - bourbon barrel aged stout
- Oude Tart with Boysenberries - Flemish-style red ale
- Humulus Triple - triple india-style pale lager

Cost is $58.50 but doesn't include tax or shipping.

The [Microbrewed Beer of the Month Club](http://www.beermonthclub.com/) offers many different options. You can choose beers from the US or international, or a mix of both. They have levels that run from 2 large format bottles up to a dozen 12-oz bottles.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head, Half-Time Beverage co. runs a few [Beer of the Month clubs](http://www.halftimebeverage.com/beer-club.html).  I've ordered beer from them, and that worked pretty well, but never tried any of their clubs.  I'm sure there are some other companies, but figuring out who can legally ship to you can get a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the UK Beer 52 is excellent https://www.beer52.com/

This has been set up by a friend of mine based in Edinburgh.  They have purposely gone out of their way to find unique and individual beers. In my first box, along with 12 beers,  I received a nice bottle opener, a little 'passport' book giving me discount to a selected number of bars, a book on the history of beer and the recent explosion of craft beer and a copy of the well regarded 'Ferment' magazine.

What I also like is they are currently trying to produce some low/no alcohol beers too, which is an increasingly important market.

Comment: Hi Simon, please expand your answer to explain what it is about this service that makes you prefer it.